# Error 1452 'Cannot add or update a child row'

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert a new record into the table Bridges, I believe the program is trying to use Bridge_ID rather than User_ID in the Bridges table. I am using MySQL with Python on an Ubuntu OS.

Things I have already tried:

1. searched stack overflow (and many other sites)
2. asked my teacher
3. dry run the code

The sql DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE User ( 
    User_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    Password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (User_ID) 
);


CREATE TABLE Bridges( 
    User_ID INT NOT NULL, 
    Bridge_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Bridge_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    BridgeFile BLOB NOT NULL, 
    Date_Last_Edit DATE NOT NULL, 
    Difficulty VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    Land_Type INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Bridge_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY User_ID REFERENCES User(User_ID) 
);
```

It is worth noting that info['User_ID'] does not change from 1 and before inserting the record the value held by User_ID is echoed to confirm this.

The query made is:

```
command = ('INSERT INTO Bridges 
                    (User_ID,Bridge_Name,Date_Last_Edit,
                    BridgeFile,Difficulty,Land_Type) 
            VALUES ("%s","%s",CURDATE(),"%s","%s","%s");'  %(info['User_ID'],name,adjacencyList,info['dif'],info['land']))
```

The error is:

> (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`BridgeBuilder`.`Bridges`, CONSTRAINT `Bridges_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Bridge_ID`) REFERENCES `User` (`User_ID`))')

If any more detail is required Ill update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value info['User_ID'] is correct. Table `Bridges` require `User_ID` exist in table `User`

Comment: Thank you, however the value of info['User_ID'] is correct. I believe what is happening is the program is trying to use Bridge_ID as the foreign key, there is already a record in the table Bridges so Bridge_ID is incremented to 2, there is no User_ID in the User table equal to 2. I am going to rebuild both tables from scratch.

Comment: Yes, this is the root cause of this problem. You should make sure the value of `User_ID` has existed in the table `User`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not correctly passing the parameters to the query.

Please try :

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO Bridges 
                (User_ID, Bridge_Name, Date_Last_Edit, BridgeFile, Difficulty, Land_Type) 
                VALUES (%s, %s, CURDATE(), %s, %s, %s)"

vals = (info['User_ID'], name, adjacencyList, info['dif'], info['land'])
```

Then you can execute the query with commands like :

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(sql, vals)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have given it a go but unfortunately it has not worked, it is still producing the same error.

Comment: OK. Can you manually dump the value of `info['User_ID']` and ensure that it does exist in the user table ?

Comment: In MySQL, it works fine : see [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f86b622e24f2c604336b5ae5942b1214). Most likely the issue comes from the python part.

Comment: I tried the query directly without the use of any python and the same error was created. However I dropped both tables and rebuilt them and the problem no longer exists. Thank you

Comment: @kirandarji : FYI there was a problem in the `CREATE TABLE Bridges` statement, where `FOREIGN KEY User_ID REFERENCES User(User_ID) ` should be written `FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES User(User_ID) `

Comment: Yes I realised that when recreating the tables however it did not perform the query due to the error, I do not remember what happened when I initially built the tables.